# On HighMaps, how do I show state abbreviations instead of state name on a U.S. map and remove data label from point

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighMaps to show a U.S. map with project locations.  I would like the map to show state abbreviations instead of the full state name, so, "AZ" instead of "Arizona".

I would also like to not show a label for the project location. I just want to show the symbol (circle or triangle).  To be specific, I am using some conditional logic to determine from the contents of a field in the data whether it is a "PV Station" or a "Soiling Station". I do not want this to show as a data label on the map, but I do want it to show on the tooltip.  Here is my map: https://www.nrel.gov/pv/soiling-map-1.html

Here is the JavaScript:

```
Highcharts.getJSON('/pv/client/js/pv-soiling-map-data.json', function (data) {

 data.map(function(elem) {
    if (elem.Measurement_type == 'Soiling station') {
        elem.name = 'Soiling Station';
        elem.marker = {symbol: 'triangle'};
    
    } else {
        elem.name = 'PV Station';
        elem.marker = {symbol: 'rectangle'};
    }
         
    if (elem.Sratio_all_data < 0.96) {
        elem.color = '#648fff';}
    else if (elem.Sratio_all_data >= 0.96 && elem.Sratio_all_data < .98) {
        elem.color = '#785ef0';}
    else if (elem.Sratio_all_data >= 0.98 && elem.Sratio_all_data < .99) {
        elem.color = '#fe6100';}
    else if (elem.Sratio_all_data >= 0.99) {
        elem.color = '#ffb000';
    } else {
        elem.color = '#dc267f';}
  });

    
  Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
      map: 'countries/us/us-all'        
    },
      title: {
        text: undefined
    },
   credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
      buttonOptions: {
        verticalAlign: 'top'
      }
    },
    legend: {
       title: {
          text: 'SRatio Range'
        },
        enabled: false,
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        itemMarginTop: 10
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Map',
      color: '#E0E0E0',
      dataLabels: {
         enabled: true,
         format: '{point.name}'
       },
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      borderColor: '#606060',
      nullColor: '#eafaec',
      showInLegend: false
    }, {
      type: 'mappoint',

      showInLegend: false,
      data: data,
      minSize: 1,
      maxSize: '25',
      point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    this.series.chart.update({
                        tooltip: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    });
                },
                mouseOut: function() {
                    this.series.chart.update({
                        tooltip: {
                            enabled: false
                        }

                    })
                }
            },
          valueDescriptionFormat: '{point.name}, {point.site}.'
        },
        tooltip: {
          shared: true,
          useHTML: true,
          headerFormat: '<table>',
          pointFormat: '<tr><td><b>{point.name}</b><br/><b>Site:</b> {point.site}<br/><b>Tilt:</b> {point.tilt}<br/><b>County:</b> {point.county}<br/><b>Mounting:</b> {point.mounting}<br/><b>Months/data set:</b> {point.#_of_Months_in_dataset}<br/><b>Median Srate:</b> {point.median_Srate}<br/><b>Sratio:</b> {point.Sratio_all_data}<br/><b>Annual Sratio:</b> {point.annualSratio}<br/><b>January Sratio:</b> {point.January_Srate}<br/><b>February Sratio:</b> {point.February_Srate}<br/><b>March Sratio:</b> {point.March_Srate}<br/><b>April Sratio:</b> {point.April_Srate}<br/><b>May Sratio:</b> {point.May_Srate}<br/><b>June Sratio:</b> {point.June_Srate}<br/><b>July Sratio:</b> {point.July_Srate}<br/><b>August Sratio:</b> {point.August_Srate}<br/><b>September Sratio:</b> {point.September_Srate}<br/><b>October Sratio:</b> {point.October_Srate}<br/><b>November Sratio:</b> {point.November_Srate}<br/><b>December Sratio:</b> {point.December_Srate}</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        valueDecimals: 2
    }
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code but without success. The path used in the getJSON feature is probably locally.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j8wkxztu/

But I think that I am able to help solve your issues.

1. Set the `dataLabels.format` as a `'{point.code}'` or `'{point.postal-code}'`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/data-class-two-ranges

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/color-axis

2. Disable `dataLabels` by setting the `dataLabels.enabled` as a false.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t8gz9sad/

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. That did fix my second issue. But the state abbreviation does not show on the state using either of those. No labels are displayed for the states.  https://www.nrel.gov/pv/soiling-map-1.html

Comment: Try setting the `dataLabels.format` as a `{point.properties.postal-code}`.